# Remove Scoll bar on Elementor Pop Up

Tags: javascript, css, addeventlistener, elementor

I am trying to remove through CSS the scroll bar that appears by default on Elementor on a Pop Up.
Can someone help ?
https://www.onservatory.com/recursos-gratuitos/

I tried different things based on similar questions but doesnt seem to work.

```
.dialog-message dialog-lightbox-message::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

or

```
#elementor-popup-modal-21529 > div > div.dialog-message.dialog-lightbox-message {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

I thought maybe I can't do it trhough CSS because the pop up shows later but then I tried to create a listener like

```
<script>

  (function() {
    // Use events from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events
    var eventName = 'elementor/popup/show';
    
    // Attach listener directly to element or document if element not found
    var el = document.querySelectorAll(".dialog-lightbox-message")[0]||document;
    
    // Leave useCapture to true if you want to avoid propagation issues.
    var useCapture = true;
    
    el.addEventListener(eventName, {{JS - Popup Event callback}}, useCapture);
  })();
  </script>
```

using the following documentation https://developers.elementor.com/elementor-pro-2-7-popup-events/ but doesn't work neither.
Can someone help ?
Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a scrollbar in the link you posted anywhere, using Firefox.

Comment: I also don't see a scrollbar in the link you provided , using chrome

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the scroll bar on the `<body>`. if it is the problem, then you need to set the `overflow` property as `overflow: hidden` for the `<body>` tag it can be done by both CSS and JS.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was an issue with the cache of the browser/cdn.
I think now it's working.
I created a new ticket on hot to avoid caching for the experts! Thank you!
[Caching on wordpress and pagebuilders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63728995/caching-on-wordpress-and-pagebuilders)
Apologies for my mistake.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Chrome and Safari:

`.elementor-popup-modal .dialog-message.dialog-lightbox-message::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}`

For Firefox use this:

`.elementor-popup-modal .dialog-message.dialog-lightbox-message { scrollbar-width: none; }`

Add it to your Popup Settings > Advanced > Custom CSS

screenshot: https://snipboard.io/PeDl18.jpg

Answer (score -1):

"Use this for Chrome and Safari:

.elementor-popup-modal .dialog-message.dialog-lightbox-message::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}

For Firefox use this:

.elementor-popup-modal .dialog-message.dialog-lightbox-message { scrollbar-width: none; }

Add it to your Popup Settings > Advanced > Custom CSS

screenshot: [https://snipboard.io/PeDl18.jpg"](https://snipboard.io/PeDl18.jpg%22)

_____ This Works!